# Accessing the composed DOM for a polymer element

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to access the browser-rendered DOM for a polymer element, without caring in the slightest which bits from from the "light" or "shadow" DOM as described in http://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html, but I cannot find any API documentation on access functions that would let me do this.

I can see the `.shadowRoots` list that is on polymer elements, and I can see the regular `.children` property, but neither of these is particularly useful to get the content that is actually being shown on the page.

What is the correct way to get the DOM fragment that is currently visible in the browser? (or if someone knows where this is documented on the polymer site, I'd love to know that too. Google couldn't find it for me)

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is to only consider your virtual DOM (and even better, only consider *local* DOM [divide and conquer ftw]).

Therefore, today, there is no (easy) way to examine the composed DOM.

There will be such a way eventually for certain specialized uses, but I encourage you to try to adopt a mental model that allows you to avoid asking this question.

Comment: this isn't about mental model: I *need* to know what the browser is showing users, not just what potential data exists =)

Comment: the problem I am facing is that I have a custom element that contains other custom elements - polymer runs through these and fires "dom insert" events when elements aren't *actually* added to the DOM, but to a dom fragment: `<a><b></b></a>` will first fire an insert for `b` into a headless domfragment, but then never fires an event when that fragment is linked into `a`: how do I know when `b` is actually used on the page, i.e. my user is looking at it, is interactive with it, and it's inside an `a` element so I can make `b` behave correctly

Comment: I'm not sure to what "dom insert events" refers to. If you mean calls to `attachedCallback` or `attached`, these are only fired when the element becomes part of the **main document**. If you have a counter example, you should post a bug report.

Comment: I tried `attachedCallback`, which fired for `b` when it was read in by Polymer, but before its ancestor chain included `a`.

Comment: I'm a bit nervous that we are having this discussion under the headline for 'composed dom', since this is not the same question at all. Fwiw, so far, you haven't described any problem that actually depends on interrogating the composed tree.

Comment: In any case, `attachedCallback` is fired when the node is considered attached to the main document (not when it's "read by Polymer"). Unfortunately, the nature of the surrounding dom and various references at that point can depend on several factors. If you are using Polymer proper, you can try `domReady` instead of `attached`. If you are using some other flavor of custom elements, try going async from `attachedCallback` (aka use setTimeout or friends wait one 'task' before trying to access surrounding DOM).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I wrote for the same purpose:

```
  function getComposedDOMChildren (root) {
    if (root.shadowRoot) {
      root = root.shadowRoot;
    }
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
      if (root.children[i].tagName === 'CONTENT') {
        children.push.apply(children, root.children[i].getDistributedNodes());
      } else if (root.children[i].tagName === 'SHADOW') {
        var shadowRoot = root;
        while (!shadowRoot.host) {
          shadowRoot = shadowRoot.parentNode;
        }
        children.push.apply(children, getComposedDOMChildren(shadowRoot.olderShadowRoot));
      } else {
        children.push(root.children[i]);
      }
    }
    return children;
  }
```

It returns an array with the children of the `root` as per the composed DOM.
It works by going into the shadow root and replacing all `<content>` elements with what is actually rendered in them and recursing with the earlier shadow root when `<shadow>` elements are found.

Of course, to get the entire DOM tree, one has to iterate through the returned array and invoke `getComposedDOMChildren` on each element.

Something like:

```
function traverse (root) {
  var children = getComposedDOMChildren(root);
  for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    traverse(children[i]);
  }
}
```

Please correct me if this isn't right.